# Solr performance on EC2 for geospatial queries

Tags: performance, solr, geolocation, geospatial

EC2 Configuration

```
mlarge machine - 
4 CPU,
7.5G,
EBS volume,
JVM Memory - 6G,
Solr Version tested on both 4.0-ALPHA and 3.6.1
```

schema.xml

```
<fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="4" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<field name="id" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />
<field name="location" type="location" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="location_0_coordinate" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="location_1_coordinate" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="text" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

No Changes in solrconfig.xml.

EDIT:

```
<query>
  <filterCache class="solr.FastLRUCache" size="512" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="0"/>
  <queryResultCache class="solr.LRUCache" size="512" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="0"/>
  <documentCache class="solr.LRUCache" size="512" initialSize="512" autowarmCount="0"/>
  <enableLazyFieldLoading>true</enableLazyFieldLoading>
  <queryResultWindowSize>20</queryResultWindowSize>
  <queryResultMaxDocsCached>200</queryResultMaxDocsCached>
  <useColdSearcher>false</useColdSearcher>
  <maxWarmingSearchers>2</maxWarmingSearchers>
</query>
```

128M records of data loaded in it.

Java client code

```
        ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
        params.set("wt","csv");
        params.set("df","id");
        params.set("fl", "id,location");
        params.set("q", "*:*");
        params.set("fq", "{!geofilt}");
        params.set("sfield", "location");
        params.set("d", "0.05");
        params.set("pt",  columns[1] +"," + columns[2]);
        QueryResponse response = solr.query(params);
```

top

```
Tasks:  71 total,   1 running,  70 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s): 38.7%us,  0.0%sy,  0.0%ni, 49.4%id,  0.0%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si, 11.9%st
Mem:   7634740k total,  7570960k used,    63780k free,   150708k buffers
Swap:        0k total,        0k used,        0k free,  3914812k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND                                                                                                                                         
956 root      20   0 25.7g 4.0g 889m S 100.1 55.2 353:48.70 java
```

So results are, that on average it takes around 1.5 secs to query a document.

```
record 203 response Time 1108 result: 42.7461000,-73.6924000, 
record 207 response Time 1123 result: 40.8448850,-73.7156030, 
record 210 response Time 1180 result: 40.8087660,-74.1583510, 
record 211 response Time 1656 result: 0, 
record 212 response Time 1423 result: 0, 
record 213 response Time 1316 result: 39.1027710,-76.7964910.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [SOLR-2155](https://github.com/dsmiley/SOLR-2155), a drop-in geospatial plugin for Solr 3.x

The underlying algorithm / approach is the heart of the new spatial module in Lucene/Solr 4.  People tell me they use SOLR-2155 because it outperforms LatLonType.

After you try out SOLR-2155 and tell us how fast it is under the same circumstances, then I suggest sharding your index into 2-3 shards and doing a distributed search.

Comment: Sure, I will give it a try. But I got similar performance results with Solr 4.0.0-ALPHA.

Comment: Solr 4.0.0-ALPHA doesn't *yet* use the new Lucene spatial module, but it will.  LatLonType will stay as is, this will bring in new field types.

Comment: Great!! I dropped in SOLR-2155 plugin and the performance has improved vastly. And people are right!!.                                                       record 2225 response Time 79 result:  [36.23622997663915,-115.17244996502995]
record 2226 response Time 174 result: [41.825548047199845,-88.05724399164319]
record 2227 response Time 62 result: [41.99102492071688,-88.30942897126079]
record 2230 response Time 142 result: [40.662010135129094,-73.88779459521174]
Should I make any memory setting changes in solrconfig.xml file to further improve performance.  Thanks much.

Comment: I'm super pleased to see it's working so well for you.  It's hard to interpret your response but it appears you're getting 62-142 milliseconds?  Sorting is a memory pig so avoid it if you can.  Otherwise, this plugin doesn't explicitly use any memory.  For max performance use a geohash length that meets your needs and no longer.  Length 10 equates to sub-meter precision, maybe you could use less precision?  See the table at Wikipedia for geohash.  Optimizing the index to fewer segments will help performance too.

Comment: I played around with configuration for 128M records: Precision Length = 10 , JVM 6G, response around 60 -150ms  ;   Length = 10, JVM = 4G, response time 10 - 30ms ;   Length = 10, JVM = 2G, response time 10 - 30ms.  Any other suggestions on configuration, so I can further reduce response time. Also could you provide me with link to efficiently shard the solr servers. Thanks again

Comment: I suggest you buy my book ;-)  Give Java/Solr as much RAM as it needs to do its job but no more, so that the O.S. can use the rest for disk I/O caching.  Your performance numbers show how true this is. And a machine with only 7.5GB of RAM strikes me as small for serving 128M documents.  An SSD drive will do wonders for Solr, and Amazon has them now.  Sharding in Solr prior to v4 is something you do manually by choosing which Solr to write to, but it will do the [distributed search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch) across the shards easily.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one for starters: if by **No Changes for solrconfig.xml.** you mean you are using the one in \example without any changes, you have a crapload of stuff that you probably don't need (as it is an example, showing many different features), so remove things you don't need from there (mostly fields I think) and test again.

Comment: Yes, solrconfig.xml was from \example folder. Well, I looked at it, but most of stuff is commented except in the under query tag.